# What does this numpy array means?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am new to numpy and was trying to build a 3d array but missed a square bracket and came up with something interesting which I wasn't able to understand so I am asking here.
My code was

```
 x = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
```

notice that pattern here is

```
 x = np.array([[list,list],list,list])
```

and output was

```
array([list([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]), list([7, 8, 9]), list([10, 11, 12])],
  dtype=object)
```

and its shape was

```
In [8]: x.shape                                                                 
Out[8]: (3,)
```

Which I am not understanding.
And when I did

```
x = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
```

I got the expected result

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
    [ 4,  5,  6]],

   [[ 7,  8,  9],
    [10, 11, 12]]])
```

and expected shape

```
 x.shape

(2, 2, 3)
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: It's a one-dimensional numpy array with size 3 containing lists (or list of lists) as its elements, as indicated by `dtype=object`. Numpy leaves the lists as actual lists inside the array because it can't coerce them into proper arrays due the different structure of the first element, compared to the others.

Comment: This makes some sense